# boolean operator in for loop in c++

Tags: c++, operators

I know how to program in Java, but I am trying to learn C++. I am trying to do some contest in where they present you an algorithm and you try to solve it using any language you want.

I was stuck on one algorithm and searching I found this piece of code that might be helpful for me but I am a little confused in the last part of the statement in the for loop

```
  int N,K;
  scanf("%d %d",&N,&K);   

  for(int j = 0,x;j<N;++j){
          scanf("%d",&x);
          x = N+1-x;

          for(int idx = x-1;idx>0;idx -= (idx & -idx)) aux2 += T[idx];
```

I am confused in the part:

```
idx -= (idx & -idx)
```

I know that "-=" is equivalent to:

```
idx = idx - (idx & -idx)
```

and I know that "&" is the logic operation AND
but I don't know how can you operate an integer with a boolean.. for a java guy like me this is a little bit confusing.

I was wondering if someone could help me here.

Comment: & is the bitwise AND operator. This part would be perfectly legal in Java too.

Comment: It operates bit by bit. For an explanation, see http://community.topcoder.com/tc?module=Static&d1=tutorials&d2=binaryIndexedTrees

Comment: FYI, `idx -= idx & -idx` is also equivalent to `idx &= idx - 1`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The expression `idx -= (idx & -idx)` sets the lowest bit in `idx` whose value is 1 to 0.

For example, 10001010010 ==> 10001010000.

So the number of iterations in the loop above will be equal to the number of 1s in `idx`.

BTW, a simpler way to perform this operation is with `idx &= idx-1`.

The [SWAR Algorithm](http://aggregate.org/MAGIC/#Population%20Count%20%28Ones%20Count%29) is considered to be the most efficient way to count the number of 1s.

Comment: That expression, `idx -= (idx & -idx)`, is cryptic. I sure wouldn't have been able to guess what it means without your answer. Is that the most efficient way to count the number of `1` bits?

Answer (score 2):

bitwise operators operate, well on each bit of  their arguments. In particular, `&` applies the AND operator , so an example (for 4bit arguments) would be

```
  0101
& 1011
------
  0001
```

Answer (score 2):

you're [confusing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B#Operator_precedence) bitwise operators with boolean operators.

- `operator &` is the **binary** (aka *bitwise*) **AND** operator. In the case of integers, it does an AND operation on each and every bit. So for example: `1 & 2` is equal `0`.
- `operator &&` is the **boolean and** operator (aka *logical AND*). In C++ it takes two values (not only `bool`, `int`s will do too), and checks if both of them are `true` (in the case of integers - not equal to `0`).

In C++, `idx && -idx` would be legal too, and would be equal `true` if `idx` wasn't `0`, but it wouldn't do the same as in the current version.